# Test resolution is blocked when the expected condition fails

Tags: protractor, mocha.js

With Protractor, and using Mocha framework, I am comparing two arrays of values, one from a bar chart, one from text fields.
The code looks like this:

```
it("Each bar should have a value equal to its percentage", () => {
    var identicalValue: boolean = false;
    helper.getFirstValues(textLocator).then((textValue) => {
        helper.getBarValues(barLocator).then((barValue) => {
            identicalValue = helper.compareArray(textValue, barValue);
            //compareArray returns a boolean, true if the arrays have the same values
            expect(identicalValue).to.equal(true);
        });
    });
});
```

the functions are coded this way:

```
public getFirstValues(factsheetTab: protractor.ElementFinder): webdriver.promise.Promise<{}> {

    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    factsheetTab.all(by.tagName("tr")).map((ele, index) => {
        return {
            index: index,
            text: ele.all(by.tagName("td")).first().getText()
        }
    }).then((topValue) => {
        deferred.fulfill(topValue);
    },
        (reason) => { deferred.reject(reason) });
    return deferred.promise;
};

public getBarValues(factsheetTab: protractor.ElementFinder): webdriver.promise.Promise<{}> {

    var deferred = protractor.promise.defer();
    factsheetTab.all(by.tagName("tr")).map((ele, index) => {
            return {
                index: index,
                text: ele.all(by.tagName("td")).last().element(by.tagName("div")).getAttribute("data-value")
            }
    }).then((barValue) => {
        deferred.fulfill(barValue);
    },
    (reason) => { deferred.reject(reason) });
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

My problem is that when the comparison returns false, so when the two arrays have differences, the test is blocked. It doesn't fail, the browser remains opened on that step, and the process stops, ignoring the remaining tasks.

Note: the function helper.compareArray returns a correct value. I could also write "expect(false).to.equal(true)" and get blocked too.

Am I doing something wrong in this test? Do you see a reason why this test is not finished?

edit: I found a workaround, to not get stuck in case of the test failing:

```
it("Each bar should have a value equal to its percentage", () => {
    var identicalValue: boolean = false;
    var textValue = null;
    helper.getFirstValues(textLocator).then((value) => {
        textValue = value;
    });
    helper.getBarValues(barLocator).then((barValue) => {
        chai.assert.deepEqual(barValue, textValue);
    });
});
```

(using @Brine's suggestion, for the deepEqual)

This seems to work, the other tests are ran if this one fails. 
I'm still curious to know what was wrong with the first version though.

Comment: maybe try substituting with `.to.be.true;`? generally you should use that as it is exactly what you are trying to do

Comment: I just tried it, but unfortunately, it doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Without seeing the code of your custom code we can only guess wildly at what *could* be wrong there.

Comment: I added the 2 functions, if that can help.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this is a bug in your `helper.compareArray` or Mocha... but why not compare the arrays directly? I don't use Mocha but it seems something like this would work:

```
expect(textValue).deepEqual(barValue);
```

Comment: I didn't know about that function, thanks ! it doesn't solve the issue though. I tried to use it, commenting my helper.compareArray part, and the result is the same (blocked on failure, and goes through on success)

Comment: Cool! My guess would be mocha promise issues, or a flat out mocha bug? Not sure. Protractor tweaks Jasmine to handle all the promises within the expect, so that's another option... glad it helped a bit.